# typeof undefined object does not equal type of undefined variable

Tags: javascript, types

In JavaScript, `typeof {}` returns "object", while evaluating `{}` returns undefined. Why is this?

```
var a;
a; //undefined
{}; //undefined
typeof a === typeof {}; //false
```

Comment: Why would an empty object be undefined? Where did you come up with that!

Comment: when you mean evaluating, are you meaning `eval()`

Comment: @adeneo It is when it's considered an empty block :)

Comment: @Ian - Indeed, just randomly typing `{}` does not an object make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `typeof a` is `"undefined"` and `typeof {}` is `"object"`:

```
console.log(typeof a);    // "undefined"
console.log(typeof {});   // "object"
```

Also, as @adeneo commented, `{}` is not `undefined`:

```
console.log({} == undefined);    // false
```

Comment: E.g., the question is based on a misconception: `{}` is not "undefined" in any sense of the word, and certainly not in the technical sense of having the type `"undefined"`.